# How can I turn this nested JSON into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a piece of JSON code and I want to turn it into a DataFrame, however I am quite new to DataFrames so I am a bit stuck. Any help would be appreciated :)

So this is my code:

```
data = response.json()

data_pretty = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pretty print
print(data_pretty)
print(data_frame)
```

This is the output:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "users": [
        {
            "email": "raf@webconexus.nl",
            "first_name": "Raf",
            "id": "24959",
            "last_name": "Rasenberg"
        },
        {
            "email": "raf.rasenberg@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "Raf",
            "id": "25795",
            "last_name": "Rasenberg"
        }
    ]
}
  status                                              users
0     OK  {'id': '24959', 'email': 'raf@webconexus.nl', ...
1     OK  {'id': '25795', 'email': 'raf.rasenberg@gmail....
```

As you can see it needs some additional tweaking, I only want to show the columns 'email', 'first_name', 'id' and 'last_name'. Can someone help me out?

Comment: do you need something more complex than `pd.DataFrame(data.get('users'))`?

Comment: Cool that was the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to select list of rows:

```
pd.DataFrame(data.get('users'))
```

Comment: alternatively `pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, record_path='users')`